# Why my service is autowired to a Proxy?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop, autowired

Hi I've got this class to do test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/service.xml"})
public class Test {

    @Autowired private CommonService commonService;
```

while debuging, I get on CommonService an Object with an attribute h which is a SdkDynamicAopProxy.

How can I get on my attribute commonService one CommonServiceImp Object?

commonService

```
public interface CommonService {...}
```

CommonServiceImp

```
@Service("commonService")
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public class CommonServiceImp implements CommonService {
    @Autowired private CommonDaoJdbcImp commonDao; ...}
```

service.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="/bbb-dao.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="aaa.bbb.service"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" /> -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
<task:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: your question is unclear: if you invoke a method on the proxy, it will be executed by your concrete implementation. What is the problem that you're seeing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `CommonServiceImp` class is annotated with `@Transactional` and you have an application context which does transaction management with `<tx:annotation-driven />` and the transaction manager bean. Spring uses proxies to achieve this behavior and intercept all your method calls and wrap them with the transactional behavior. That is why you see a `SdkDynamicAopProxy` and not the Type of your class.

[See the official documentation.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: Thanks, and how can I fix my code on order to get my commonService populated with the correct Object a CommonService? and if it isn't possible, how could I manage the Proxy Object to use my service's methods? thanks in advance.

Comment: You could disable the transaction management, but I doubt you want that. The proxy will eventually call your methods (that is the purpose of this kind of proxy), but only after it calls its own.

Comment: What Class could I use to instance this Proxy object? is it a Spring Class or a java one?.

Comment: Spring does it for you. If it needs to proxy a class, it uses the cglib library to instantiate a proxy that has the same type as your class. If it neeeds to proxy an interface, it uses java's proxy api. You don't really have control over this.